# Issue in converting column to datetime in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a csv and am reading the csv using the following code

```
df1 = pd.read_csv('dataDate.csv');

df1
Out[57]: 
             Date
0      01/01/2019
1      01/01/2019
2      01/01/2019
3      01/01/2019
4      01/01/2019
5      01/01/2019
```

Currently the column has `dtype : dtype('O')` I am now doing the following command to convert the following date to datetime in the format %d/%m/%Y

```
df1.Date = pd.to_datetime(df1.Date, format='%d/%m/%Y')
```

It produces output as :

```
9    2019-01-01
35   2019-01-01
48   2019-01-01
38   2019-01-01
18   2019-01-01
36   2019-01-01
31   2019-01-01
6    2019-01-01
```

Not sure what is wrong here, I want the same format as the input for my process. Can anyone tell what's wrong with the same?

Thanks

Comment: Nothing's wrong, it's just the default output format of `pd.to_datetime `. This function is aimed to provide for datetime operations, if what is relevant is the final format, simply convert to string again

Comment: @yatu How can I obtain the same format %d/%m/%Y while converting to datetime object and why it isn't taking the same.

Comment: @vp7 you can't. it's the string **representation** of Python's datetime objects.

Answer (score 0):

The produced output is the default format for pandas' `datetime` object, so there is nothing wrong. Yet, you can play around with the format and produce a datetime string with `strftime` method. This built-in method for python is implemented in pandas.

You can try the following:

```
df1.Date = pd.to_datetime(df1.Date, format='%d/%m/%Y')
df1['my_date'] = df1.Date.dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
```

So that `'my_date'` column has the desired format. Yet, you cannot do datetime operations with that column, but you can use for representation. You can work with `Date` column for your mathematical operations, etc. and represent them with `my_date` column.